# Nested List Data not shown on first page load

Tags: stash

I've got a nested set_list that adds "tags" (which are really just relationships) to a list that the frontend then loops through.

It's set like this

```
{!-- SO: Grab relevant tags --}
{exp:stash:set_list:nested
  name="tags"
  context="{segment_3}"
  parse_tags="yes"
  save="yes"
  scope="site"
  refresh="120"
}
  {stash:tag}Blog{/stash:tag}
  {stash:url}/blog/{/stash:url}

  {exp:playa:children field="blog_contributor"}
    {stash:tag}{title}{/stash:tag}
    {stash:url}/contributor/{url_title}{/stash:url}
  {/exp:playa:children}

{/exp:stash:set_list:nested}
{!-- EO: Grab relevant tags --}
```

This works well, but only on the 2nd page refresh and after. The first time that you load the page the items set by the non-nested lists are fine but these bits are empty.

Looking at Mustash after first load it renders this:-

```
tag|=|Blog|&|url|=|/blog/|+|tag|=|Al Overdrive|&|url|=|/contributor/al-overdrive
```

But this isn't rendering on the front-end. The front-end code is

```
{exp:stash:get_list:nested name="tags" context="{segment_3}" scope="site"}
  <li><a href="{url}">{tag}</a></li>
{/exp:stash:get_list:nested}
```

I'm pretty sure I'm missing something obvious here, but any help is appreciated.

Comment: Dont think you've used the nested list properly. Nested list is for repeating content inside single content - ie. the playa field not the channel entry & playa field combined. You have set tags wrapped around nested yes ? Its definaltly a parse order issue but cant see the whole template logic.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This was being caused because I was setting the list in the same file as I was getting it. If I moved the getting down a level by having an embed like `{stash:embed:layouts:standard}` which handled the UI it resolved itself.